pgAdmin prompts for password despite correctly configured pgpass file
I am using pgAdmin in a Docker container to connect to a PostgreSQL server, which is also running in a Docker container. My docker-compose.yml looks like this:
events.database:
  image: postgres:latest
  container_name: events.database
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: events
    POSTGRES_USER: root
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
  ports:
    - "5432:5432"

pgadmin:
  container_name: pgadmin
  image: dpage/pgadmin4
  restart: unless-stopped
  environment:
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: root@root.com
    PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: root
  ports:
    - "5050:80"
  volumes:
    - ./web_API/servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
    - ./web_API/pgpass:/pgadmin4/pgpass
  entrypoint: >
    /bin/sh -c "
    cp -f /pgadmin4/pgpass /var/lib/pgadmin/;
    chmod 600 /var/lib/pgadmin/pgpass;
    chown 5050:0 /var/lib/pgadmin/pgpass;
    /entrypoint.sh
    "

The servers.json file is configured as follows:
{
  "Servers": {
    "1": {
      "Name": "Events DB",
      "Group": "Server Group 1",
      "Port": 5432,
      "Username": "root",
      "Host": "events.database",
      "SSLMode": "prefer",
      "MaintenanceDB": "postgres",
      "PassFile": "/var/lib/pgadmin/pgpass"
    }
  }
}

The pgpass file contains:
events.database:5432:*:root:root

Even though the pgpass file is correctly configured with proper ownership and permissions (600), and both containers are on the same network and can resolve each other's hostnames, pgAdmin still prompts for a password when connecting to the server. Once I manually enter the password in the pgAdmin GUI, it connects to the server and can access the databases without issues.
My Questions:

Why is pgAdmin prompting for a password even though the pgpass file is correctly set up?
How can I configure pgAdmin to automatically use the credentials from the pgpass file for the initial connection?

I've tried verifying the file permissions, ownership, and content, and have confirmed that the network settings are correct. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!






pgAdmin is  a GUI client and you log into the client first per Login Page, then  you log in to a server. You are being prompted for the GUI login and that does not involve pgpass.

Yeah, on the login page I have to enter the credentials myself. That's not the problem. But I get prompted when clicking the server.

At this point I don't have an answer.

It looks like you are both mounting to /var/lib/pgadmin/pgpass and copying to it.  I don't think that that makes sense.

O my bad, must have gone wrong when testing different variations. Changed it back as it suposed to be. Still no succes. I also edited my question so it doesnt contain this issue anymore.
